# Keep the left part of a string before a specific Character

Tags: php, string

I am looking to get the value of a particular cookie (affiliate ID) and can successfully pull this in however some cookies have some additional content in the string which I need to strip off.

For example: `AFFILIATE_www.example.com_` where I only want to obtain AFFILIATE. In all cases, the additional information is surrounded by two underscores. Is there a way I can strip off every character after and including the first underscore?

I've tried the following:

```
<?php $cookie_name = 'cbnn';
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) {
  '';
} else {
   $_COOKIE[$cookie_name];
}; ?>

<?php $aff = "$_COOKIE[$cookie_name]";
$search = “EVERYTHING AFTER AND INCLUDING THE _”
$replace = "";
echo preg_replace($search,$replace,$aff); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course:

```
$affiliate = substr($cookie, 0, strpos($cookie, '_'));
```

Your code would look something like this:

```
$cookie = $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]; // this is the part you want to parse
$affiliate = substr($cookie, 0, strpos($cookie, '_')); // this is the part you're looking for.
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not that knowledgeable and the above so far has been put together after a lot of Googling. Where exactly would I put your line of code?

Comment: $search represents your "AFFILIATE_www.example.com_" string. So when you have that, insert this line of code, it will return everything before the first underscore character. I've edited my answer, I think it makes more sense now.

Comment: So do I keep the $search and if so what do I enter after it (again sorry and thanks for the help)

Comment: See my edited answer. You don't need $search, you just need two lines of code and you're done :)

Comment: WORKING! Thanks ever so much for the help!